# Access restricted Azure App Service returns "Error 403 - This web app is stopped"

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-api-apps

I have two Allow rules in Access Restrictions for the API web app, the corporate network and the VNET subnet with a VM used for development. The API published to the App Service works as expected from the corporate network but returns Error 403 - This web app is stopped" when called from the VM.

I double checked the rule and the subnet in the rule (x.x.x.0/24) correctly reflects the VM's subnet.

What could cause this?

Comment: Does the reply solve your question?  or could you share the solution if you solve it? Other community members will benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

The VM is most likely using a public IP address to talk with the App Service, not its private IP address.

The request would need to be routed through the VM's VNET to the App Service in order for the private address to be used.

Comment: The VM has no public IP. It is accessed from the corporate network via a VM Gateway using the private VNET.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the VM subnet instead of a private CIDR range x.x.x.0/24 in the rules of Access Restrictions for the API web app. You should enable [service endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-service-endpoints-overview) on both the networking side as well as the service that it is being enabled with. If service endpoints are not already enabled with `Microsoft.Web` for the subnet that you selected, it will automatically be enabled for you unless you check the box asking not to do that.

When you finish it, you will find a virtual network/subnet as the `source` of the rule.

[image]

For more reference, you could get [Azure App Service Access Restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions).